# Caliburn.Micro issue: PropertyChangedBase, BindableCollection and AutoMapper

Tags: c#, binding, automapper, caliburn.micro, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework in my WPF application.
There is a `DataGrid` in a **View** that is binded to a `BindableCollection<SomeObjectStatus>`.

```
public class SomeObjectStatus
        {
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public bool IsInitializing { get; set; }
        }
```

I need to notify the UI somehow is any property of SomeObjectStatus is changed. The common way is to inherit `PropertyChangedBase` and Call `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` in each property setter:

```
public class SomeObjectStatus : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string _message;
        private bool _isInitializing;

        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _message)
                    return;
                _message = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            }
        }

        public bool IsInitializing
        {
            get { return _isInitializing; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _isInitializing)
                    return;
                _isInitializing = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange();
            }
        }
    }
```

But `SomeObjectStatus` is a **Model** class that I don't want to clog with a stuff like `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` etc.
I can create a clone class of `SomeObjectStatus` with same properties and implemented `PropertyChangedBase` specially for the **ViewModel**, lets call it `SomeObjectStatusWithNotify`. But in this case I need manually assign each property from `SomeObjectStatus` to `SomeObjectStatusWithNotify` when changes happen. In real project there are too much properties to assign them manually. So I need somehow to solve the question how to assign values from `SomeObjectStatus` to `SomeObjectStatusWithNotify` with same names automatically. It feels like I need AutoMapper-like functionality here. But I need to assign values to existing object instead creating a new one like AutoMapper does. Or maybe there is a elegant way to create `PropertyChangedBase` from regular class?

Comment: [Design Patterns - Problems and Solutions with Model-View-ViewModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx) this explain how to use dynamic property, I don't know if it can be adapt to your case but I think it is much easier to raise property change event from Model.

Comment: AutoMapper can assign values to an existing object if you use the correct overload of `Map()`

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed! Put it like answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoMapper can assign values to an existing object if you use the correct overload of `Map()`:

```
[TestClass]
public class C
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void M()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<SomeObject, SomeOtherObject>();

        SomeObject source =  new SomeObject {Name = "An Object"};
        SomeOtherObject target = new SomeOtherObject {Id = 123};

        Mapper.Map(source, target);

        Assert.AreEqual(123, target.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual("An Object", target.Name);
    }

    private class SomeOtherObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private class SomeObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```